# Using variable length argument lists and named parameters together

Tags: python

I need some help with figuring out Pythons `*args` and `**kwargs`. It's simple but I haven't entire wrapped my head around them. Here's one of scenarios that's bewildering to me.

I have two functions `mainfunc` and `wrapperfunc` (which is a wrapper function for the main function). It looks like this.

```
def mainfunc(fname=None, lname=None):
    print 'Firstname: ' + fname
    print 'Lastname: ' + lname

def wrapperfunc(uname, *args):
    print uname
    mainfunc(*args)
```

I can call `wrapperfunc` like this:

```
wrapperfunc('j.doe', 'john', 'doe')
```

In this method, all three parameters are positional. Since `j.doe` comes into `uname`, the other two params can be accessed by `*args`

..but is it possible to pass some of the params to `wrapperfunc` from a dict so that I can still access `uname` inside `wrapperfunc` directly and then pass the remaining positional parameters to the `mainfunc`. Something like the following snippet:

```
params = {'uname':'j.doe'}
wrapperfunc(**params, 'john', 'doe')
```

I want to access the named parameters directly inside `wrapperfunc` but pass all the positional parameters to `mainfunc`.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want. Please give some better example

Comment: You are *already* accessing `uname` inside `wrapperfunc` directly and passing the remaining args to `mainfunc`. Please explain.

Comment: I've made an edit. Please have a look. Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyword arguments must come after position arguments in Python.

```
params = {'uname':'j.doe'}
wrapperfunc('john', 'doe', **params)
```

will pass the keyword arguments after the two positional arguments,

If you want to look at an argument, but otherwise do the call normally, do:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print kwargs["uname"]
    return mainfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can generalize this to work on any function you want as a decorator.

```
def wrapper(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs["uname"]
        return mainfunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@wrapper
def foo(uname="Test"):
    return uname + "bar"

# the @decorator is equivalent to `foo = wrapper(foo)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a decorator function.  [Here's a nice example from the python docs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Easy_Dump_of_Function_Arguments)

Here's my take on your example.  Is there something specific this doesn't allow that you're looking for?

```
def wrapper(function):
  def closure(*args, **kwargs):
      print kwargs.get('uname')
      function(*args)
  return closure

@wrapper
def mainFunc(fname, lname):
  print 'Firstname:', fname
  print 'Lastname:', lname

mainFunc('john', 'doe', uname='j.doe')
kw={'uname': 'j.doe_from_dict'}
mainFunc('john', 'doe', **kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want:

```
def mainfunc(fname=None, lname=None):
    print 'Firstname: ' + fname
    print 'Lastname: ' + lname

def wrapperfunc(uname, *args, **kwargs):
    print uname
    mainfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

And in the Python console

```
>>> wrapperfunc('j.doe', 'john', lname='doe')
j.doe
Firstname: john
Lastname: doe
```

This way you can mix both regular and keyword arguments.